# English studying tense

Tags: perfect-constructions

Accouncement:”BIKE RACE 9 a.m.-10 a.m” 
Someone said:„At 8 a.m. the race hadn’t started”
Why someone used Past Perfect in this sentence?

Accouncement:”SKI JUMPING COMPETITION 11 a.m.-1 p.m.”
Someone wrote: „When I arrived at 11.30 a.m., the competition had begun” 
Why someone used Past Perfect in this sentence?

Answer (score 0):

> At 8 a.m. the race hadn’t started.

Presumably this was said soemtiems after 8 am, when the action was already in the past.

> When I arrived at 11.30 a.m., the competition had begun.

This would have been written at some later time, when 11:30 was already in the past.

> At time T, X had started.

The4 start is in the past of T, and T is in the past of the4 speaker/writer. so this "had" form, the past perfect, is used to show a sequence of events, all of which are in the past. First came the start, then came T, and later yet the present in which the speaker describes these events.

> At time T, X had not begun.

Again a past sequence is begin shown. during the priod before T, X did not stsart. Then came T, and finally the speaker's present.

The past perfect is used for these situations.

[This Your Dictionary article](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/past-perfect-tense-examples.html) descries the past perfect and its uses.